# Unable to install R package BMR in Ubuntu, Fedora and Windows 7 properly

Tags: r, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, cran

While installing BMR (Bayesian Macroeconometrics in R) package in any of the above-mentioned Operating systems I am getting the following Warning/Error message:

Warning: S3 methods ‘modecheck.Rcpp_dsge_gensys’, ‘modecheck.Rcpp_dsgevar_gensys’ were declared in NAMESPACE but not found

Kindly help.
the link to the above package installation instructions given below:
http://www.kthohr.com/bmr

Comment: https://rdrr.io/github/kthohr/BMR/man/BMR-package.html

Comment: http://www.kthohr.com/bmr

Comment: The instructions for proper question creation strongly suggest NOT using comments for amendments to questions. Use [edit]